# Unicode regex expression to POSIX expression conversion to support in Redshift/ Postgresql

Tags: regex, unicode, amazon-redshift, posix-ere

I've been trying to convert a unicode regex to POSIX regex to remove `\p{So}` , `\p{Cs}`, `\p{Cn}` and `\x1A` type of characters from a column.

In Informatica I was using `reg_replace (col_name,'[\p{So}\p{Cs}\p{Cn}\x1A]',' ')` function to filter out these kind of characters and replace them with a single space.

However, when migrating to RedShift the same regex is not working with **`REGEXP_REPLACE()`** as it does not support the Unicode blocks.

For e.g. this is the string :-

> **'INT¡®L n°1 di KONGRESSE Ä Ê Í EUROREGIONE. V.Ž?#'**

From above string, I need to keep the Latin / French letters, alphanumeric & punctuations and just  remove the other symbols.

Comment: The sample looks like you have [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) input.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
[^À-Ž[:punct:][:alnum:]]
```

It matches any single char other than letters from `À` to `Ž`, punctuation and alphanumerics. If `[:alnum:]` is Unicode-aware in your environment, you may remove `À-Ž`.

It also appears that you still can use a PCRE regex with [Amazon Redshift `REGEXP_REPLACE`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/REGEXP_REPLACE.html) provided you pass the `p` *parameters* option:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(col_name,'[\\p{So}\\p{Cs}\\p{Cn}\\x1A]+',' ', 1, 'p')
```

The backslashes need doubling, `1` param is the position in string to start matching from and the `p` option tells `REGEXP_REPLACE` to use PCRE regex syntax.

Comment: Hi Wiktor, Thanks for your answer. However, using this pattern also it mistakenly matched the alphabets 'So', 'Cs', 'Cn' and not being used as it's supposed to.

Comment: @PranayPurohit Does `'[\x1A]+'` or `'[\\x1A]+'` remove the `¡` char? It is possible to create a specific character class if this works. It is also important to check if `'[\u001A]+'` / `'[\\u001A]+'` works

Comment: none of those are working not sure why even with double backslashes. Hence, came up with this pattern combination. `[^À-Ž[:punct:][:alnum:]]`

Comment: @PranayPurohit Ok, maybe it is some versioning issue. I added the pattern with an explanation to the answer.